# Ignoring Form.destroy when closing the android app

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have one problem when I close my app under android, it's call the TmyMainForm.destroy, and this can take some time to free everything. The problem is that all dephi apps are with launchMode="singleTask", so still, the app is not fully closed, you can not launch it again. Now I feel that I can simply do nothing in the procedure `TmyMainForm.destroy`, even don't call inherited. This seam to work in the tests I did but I m afraid that I do not see some problems this can produce like for example crashing the app because one HTTP connection was working and thus producing report, etc..

question: is it acceptable to ignore `TmyMainForm.destroy` under android? else is there something like halt in android to stop/kill immediately the app ?

Comment: You *could* use the exit method on the System class (an import is here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/API/DW.Androidapi.JNI.Os.pas), however it is advised against. Another option might be to call the finish method on the Activity (I have not tested this)

Comment: It probably takes time because of all the ARC handling. How many objects are still alive in your UI when it is closed? FYI, Embarcadero is removing ARC in Delphi 10.4, so maybe things will run faster for you after an upgrade.

Comment: @RemyLebeau many, but for exemple if one HTTP connection was working then the free is not immediate and need to wait the closing of the connection (and if the connection was hanging its can take time). but yes with arc even if i do nothing in the destroy the object will be free even :(

Comment: @DaveNottage thank i will take a look!

Comment: @loki What's stopping you from simply closing the connection before closing the form? Closing a TCP connection should not take a lot of time, especially if you use an abortive close.

Comment: @RemyLebeau problem is if the connection is frozen (ex: bad connection), and thus the thread who own the connection is frozen then no way to kill properly everything

Comment: @RemyLebeau you also have some thread that can not be kill immediately, because thread exit only when their execute implementation check their terminated properties. so if thread is in deadlock then you are waiting :(

Comment: @DaveNottage I try with activity.finish, it's do nothing and don't stop to app immediately. The exit in opposite close immediately the app and I can relaunch it immediately. exit is perfect but i have in the log VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped. don't know what mean cleanup skipped

Comment: @DaveNottage I found that we can also call runtime.halt(0), it's more abrupt to close the app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097552/why-runtime-halt0-must-be-used-with-caution

Comment: @loki a deadlocked thread is one thing. That is a bug in your code. But what you say about a "bad connection" freezing the thread makes no sense. There are ways to close a connection across thread boundaries. You can also use a connection asynchronously so the thread can still remain responsive to terminate requests while an operation is in progress.

Comment: @RemyLebeau bug are always here :) most of the time I don't use connection asynchronously, because it's raise more problem than it's solve ...